# How to export/import local termstore?

Tags: term-store

I am using sp2010. I would like to make an export from a local termstore. After this I would like to import it on site collection. What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent article that outlines many options

[Synchronize, Import or Copy Term Stores & Managed Metadata in SharePoint Between Environments](http://www.matthewjbailey.com/synchronize-import-or-copy-term-stores-managed-metadata-in-sharepoint/)

Which is best for you depends on your exact requirements.

For my requirements I found number 5, the PowerShell cmdlets by Gary Lapointe/Aptillon to be very good.  It can export/import most things including GUIDs, Multilingual Labels, Synonyms, Sort Order, and Custom Properties.  You can even target what portion of the Term Store you want to import/export (i.e. Term Store, Group, or Term Set)

Answer (score 0):

We can actually adopt two approaches

1. Export Term Stores in a .csv file and then Import them to target server.
2. Use a powershell script to create a .cab file to import on target server.

The first approach is easier but has a major drawback. It does not persist the GUID of the terms. This may lead to many errors in the imported site because some web parts might be dependent on a term's guid.

So a better and safe way is to export and import MMS using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that i found, is take backup of Managed Metadata Service database, restore it on target server, then create new Managed Metadata Service and for database give the name of database that you restored, that's it.